# Cut one polygon into smaller polygon with other polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

I want to use one layer with numerous polygons in it (layer 2 in attached image) to cut a big polygon on another layer (layer 1 in image), so that said big polygon is separated into smaller polygons.

For example, these are drainage areas that run across a landscape, but the different sections in between these drainage areas have different sensitivities and must be classified differently. That is the aim of this exercise. Hope it makes sense!

I have been unable to figure how to do this with either standard vector tools or with plugins (like clipper or digitize tools).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with `difference`?

Comment: For some reason difference does not split it completely. Actually, only one part gets separated completely, the rest stays connected by thin lines, even though the parts of layer 2 are snapped to the border of layer one. See here (sorry, not sure how to load a pic in a comment): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fvrPxpdcY8BqrtOJjnJQcuUtWxoupRbJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Create buffer zones with round edges from layer 2 and cut them out of layer 1... You may need a one-way buffer tool as they are not equal to...